# Which HTTP headers can be used to determine whether or not the browser enables javascript?

Tags: javascript, http, web-applications, http-headers

Which HTTP headers can be used to determine whether or not the browser enables javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None. The browser doesn't send that information to the server.

Use [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement).